# How to customize regex for input type tel in html5?

Tags: regex, html

This is my current Regex:

```
<input type="tel" name="phone" value="" placeholder="Phone Number" title="019XXXXXXX" required pattern="[0-9]{2}[0-9]{3}[0-9]{3}[0-9]{4}">
```

It forces users to key in 12 digits to pass through the validation.
But all I want to do is, to allow users to key in up to 12 digits ,min would be 9. ANd they can opt to include + sign too. Also except for the +, the rest must be numbers only.

How to modify the regex pattern for this rules please?

Comment: Try `^[+]?[0-9]{9,12}$`.

Comment: don't you just hate web sites that force their funky patterns and validations on things in forms like phone numbers?  Also, are you going to call the user back?  if not, why do you want their number?  Let them use spaces, hyphens, etc. as they please!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this,

```
required pattern="^[+]?[0-9]{9,12}$"
```

`[+]?` matches an optional `+` symbol.

Comment: or `"^\\+?[0-9]{9,12}$"`

Comment: + symbol not accepting with this patter "^\\+?[0-9]{9,12}$" nor with the mentioned just above that